# background color flash sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make the background of the flashBackground flash white. How can i do this using sprite kit. I've created the SKSpriteNode below which i would like to flash from clearcolor to whitecolor to clearcolor.

```
flashBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:
                       CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];

[self addChild:flashBackground];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0]; // 1 sec delay

SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    flashBackground.color = [SKColor whiteColor];
}];

SKAction *block1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    flashBackground.color = [SKColor clearColor];
}];

[flashBackground runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait0, block0, wait0, block1]]]];
```

or for just once change the last line to:

```
[flashBackground runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait0, block0, wait0, block1]]];
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably just use a white node and animate it's alpha, but that's personal preference and probably doesn't affect anything at all.

To animate a node's color, use the [SKAction colorizeWithColor: colorBlendFactor: duration:] method. In your case, that would look like this:

```
 [flashBackground runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] colorBlendFactor:1 duration:.1],[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] colorBlendFactor:1 duration:.1]]]];
```

The alpha-based version of this would just start off with the initial color set to whiteColor, flashBackground.alpha set to 0, and run:

```
 [flashBackground runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeInWithDuration:.1],[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:.1]]]];
```

tweak the durations until you get the desired effect.

You can also try changing the node's blend mode to add or multiply, to get a more realistic flashing effect.

```
flashBackground.blendMode = SKBlendModeAdd;
```

Comment: I have no idea how alternate blend modes would handle blending clearColor into the drawing hierarchy. Feel free to share results if you try that!